# Expresso Store iDEAL update status?

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

I was wondering if anybody knows what the status is on Store updating the iDEAL payment method.
Is it gonna be updated to the new version of iDEAL in the next version of Store?
Is there a release date already?

Any information will be helpull.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these type of questions it is usually best to email support@exp-resso.com.

Having said that a new version of Store is currently under active development which will support iDEAL v3 but I do not have an estimated release date. You should be able to contact iDEAL about having v2 implemented for your account which will allow you to use it with the currently released version of Store (1.6.4).